# como se pone color a una celda en XLS?

Tags: xml, xsl, xls

Buenas no se como poner color a la celda al siguiente XLS en cuestion ahora mismo lo tengo asi el trozo, alguien me puede ayudar o decirme donde esta el error solo necesito poner las celdas en colores o saber como cambiarlas de formato yo lo he intentado desde atributo y con la variable pero no se si estara añadida correctamente:

```
<xsl:for-each select="concesionario/vehiculo">
          <tr>
                    <xsl:variable name="estilo-tipo">
                    <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    background-color:yellow;
              
                
                <xsl:value-of select="tipo"/>
               
                <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="tipo='Coche'">
               background-color:yellow;
               </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="tipo='Moto'">
                background-color:blue;
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                background-color:green;
              </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
             </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:variable>  
        </tr>
          
        
        
                        
              <table border="1">
                  <tr>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="tipo"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="matricula"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="modelo"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: esta mal el formato de salida, es mejor que uses una variable para que tengas algo como    <tr bgcolor="{color}">

Comment: Buenas de nuevo estoy empezando en este mundo, (perdona mi ignorancia si es algo evidente ) pero no lo consigo;  podrías echarme un cable amigo a reacerlo bien; te lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: revisa el siguiente codigo esto te dara una idea: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_choose